# Changing default line discipline at kernel level/ any way other than( user space) IOCTL TCIOCSETD

Tags: c, linux-kernel

I am implementing a custom line discipline in order to communicate with the peripheral connected to the serial port. So during kernel boot itself i want to assign the custom line discipline to serial port which is connected to the peripheral. When i walk through the kernel source, i come to know that by default all the serial port will be assigned `n_tty` line discipline with this function `tty_ldisc_init(struct tty_struct *tty)`.

Now how can I identify the particular serial port and assign custom line discipline?

I searched a lot , i am getting all the reference from user space.
I have a dependency, because two component will be using this line discipline. i component can access from user space while the other is in  kernel space.
So if user space component is not up, kernel space module cannot communicate